# What obligations are incurred by registering as a German resident?

Tags: germany, residency

I'm a Norwegian citizen, and am considering spending extended periods of time in Germany, potentially to the point of being a resident for some or all of a tax year. I currently live outside the EEA in a country with a tax treaty with Germany.

I understand the need to register as a resident should I spend significant amounts of time there. However, it is also possible to register as a resident before it is required.

What are my obligations should I register as a resident in Germany? The main one is likely to be dealing with tax; are there others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main one for my wife was that she was required to have health insurance. If your Norwegian health insurance covers you you might be ok. Otherwise you'll have to have health insurance (back-paid) from the day you enter the country (the time you apply for residence).